# Solving a Variable Separable Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is $$y'=\frac{1}{18}x(81-y^2)$$ with $y(0)=81$, and I have to solve for an equation of the form $y(x)$

So I do

$$\frac{dy}{(81-y^2)}=\frac{1}{18}x \ dx$$

I integrate both sides, and get

$$\frac{1}{18}\Big(\ln(-y-9)-\ln(y-9)\Big)=\frac{x^2}{36}+C$$

But the problem is that $\ln(-81-9)$ doesn't exist, and if I use absolute value signs (as I should) then I can't solve for an equation of the form

$$y(x)=$$

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It is easier to use the following relation $\frac{d}{dt}\text{arctanh}(t) = \frac{1}{1-t^2}$ when solving the integral. Then inverting it in the end becomes easier.

Comment: It should be $x^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, written in implicit form, is
$$\frac1{18}\big(\ln|y + 9| - \ln|y - 9|\big) = \frac{x^2}{36} + C$$
Using the properties of the logarithms rewrite it in a more manageable form:
$$\frac1{18}\ln\left|\frac{y + 9}{y - 9}\right| = \frac{x^2}{36} + C\tag{1}$$
Now, first of all substitute $x = 0$ and $y = 81$ to find $C$:
$$C =\frac1{18}\ln\left|\frac{81 + 9}{81 - 9}\right| - 0 = \frac1{18}\ln\frac54\tag{2}$$

For the sake of readability, I'll keep $C$ in the next manipulations.
Now, back to $(1)$. Observe that
$$\frac{y + 9}{y - 9} = 1 + \frac{18}{y-9}$$
Therefore $(1)$ becomes
$$\begin{align}
\frac1{18}\ln\left|1 + \frac{18}{y-9}\right| = \frac{x^2}{36} + C&\implies\\
\ln\left|1 + \frac{18}{y-9}\right| = \frac{x^2}{2} + C&\implies\\
1 + \frac{18}{y-9} = C\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)&\implies\\
\dots\qquad\qquad&
\end{align}$$

I'm confident you can finish from here.

Comment: @George: Is my answer sufficient? If so, could you accept it? If not, I'm happy to clarify anything!

Comment: Sorry I got busy and wasn't able to try it until now, I work it out from what you said (which looks all good) and I get $\frac{18}{(5/4)e^{x^2}-1}+9=y$, would you agree with this?  Thanks

Comment: @George: The solution, in explicit form, is:$$y(x) = \frac{18}{C\exp\left(\frac{x^2}2\right) - 1} + 9.$$ Substituting $C$ from $(2)$ you get:$$y(x) = \frac{18}{\frac1{18}\ln\left(\frac54\right)\exp\left(\frac{x^2}2\right) - 1} + 9$$, which you can simplify as needed.

Comment: Why is the C value found earlier the same C value found here?  Weren't manipulations done to it such as multiplying it by 18, and then putting it to the power of e?

Comment: @George: It's the same because $(1)$ represents the same function you find at the end, albeit in implicit form. In particular, $(1)$, relates *every* possible $x$ with the corresponding $y$. So it holds for the point $(0, 81)$ as well.